# How to prevent double quotes being removed from outerHTML/innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some Javascript in a legacy page I'm working with that reads the entire HTML of a page so that it can be saved to a file:

```
html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

However this and the `innerHTML` alternative both strip off the double quotes around some attribute values resulting in HTML that I can't use for later processing.

e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

becomes

```
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
```

When I 'View Source' the quotes are correct so how can I get the correct HTML with Javascript? My development environment is Visual Studio 2013 and Internet Explorer 10 (in quirks mode) in case that's relevant.

Clarification: The first step of the later processing is to load the HTML into an XMLDocument. The problem is that this fails because of the missing double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers do not do that, and according to HTML5 CR, all attribute values appear in double quotation marks in serialization, even in HTML serialization. But IE 8 and older use partly different serialization. The result is still correct by HTML rules, though not by XHTML rules (but IE 8 and older don’t support XHTML—they digest XHTML but only because their tag soup parsers are permissive).

You might consider using a postprocessor that converts HTML to XHTML. Or you could write your own function that is equivalent to getting `outerHTML` in modern browsers. The serializations are defined in detail in HTML5, so this would be relatively straightforward.

Comment: would you please provide any link for that?

Answer (score 1):

Both outherHtml and innerHtml do not guarantee to give you the same html that you see in the source. the browser serializes the elements into a string, rather than returning the actual source html code.

One workaround is to return innerhtml of parent element rather then outerhtml of the element. This is sometimes more accurate. Of couse, this assumes the parent has no other children.
However, you are going for the entire document, so there is no parent element.

I think the solution would entail another approach for entire document. Perhpas requestng the page in ajax call, and sending the entire response to the server.

What pages does this code run in? is it in a page that you control in your own site, or is it included in many sites that you do not control?  Does the html content of the page change by user input, or are you trying to get the page just as it appears when returned from server?

Answer (score 0):

> How to prevent double quotes being removed from outerHTML?

You can't. But the browser will only do that if the HTML specification allows it.

> However this strips off the double quotes around some attribute values resulting in HTML that I can't use for later processing.

This problem is best solved by fixing the processor so it can handle HTML instead of trying to force the client to provide whatever it is the processor is expecting.

You could probably hack around it by passing it through an HTML parser and an XHTML serializer in whatever language you are processed the file with, but just using an HTML parser is a simpler option.